# How can I make Node.js require files ignoring case even on case-sensitive file systems?

Tags: node.js, case-sensitive

I want to use a library ([rtf](https://github.com/jrowny/node-rtf)), but that library `require`s files with different casing than the actual filenames; the file is called `align.js` but is `require`d as `Align`.

Is there a way to tell Node.js to ignore casing when `require`ing files so I can use this terrible library on case-sensitive file systems?

Comment: Submit a pull request on GitHub to fix the issue? Fork the project and fix it yourself? There's not a way AFAIK to tell Node to do this; it'd have to be supported by the filesystem, or Node'll have to check align, aLign, alIgn, aLIgn etc.

Comment: Or Node.js can just `ls` and convert all the filenames to lowercase, then compare. :) I already sent a pull-request, but the npm version is not yet updated so I guess I'll have to wait for that.

Comment: @Zoidberg Specify your repo in `package.json` until the npm package is updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs require - module name case sensitive issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289065/nodejs-require-module-name-case-sensitive-issue)