# nodejs require - module name case sensitive issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

recently i found out a strange problem regarding the node.js require mechanism

you might think, due to windows file system it doesn't matter if required modules are case sensitive or not. So ...

Module A:

```
require("fancyModule");
```

Module B:

```
require("fancymodule");
```

are both leading to to the same fancymodule.js file. but the constructor of that object will be called twice. so

```
var FancyModule = {
    var name = "unkown";
    var setName = function(val){
        name = val
    }
    return {
        setName:setName
    }
}
module.exports = FancyModule();
```

will result into two separate FancyModule instances. so be aware of it.

I know that i always have to care about the right file name - no matter if the file system is case sensitive or not.

my question is, 
is there any way to setup or configure nodejs to prevent that - or at least print out a warning ?

Comment: Why are you `require()`-ing it twice in the first place?

Comment: thats just an example to make clear the problem.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, never make assumptions about the filesystem you are using.
Always expect it to be case sensitive, in case you run it in a different environment.

Now to your problem:

When you require a module in node, node will cache the import exactly to prevent the case where you want to export a singleton and not have it initialized twice.
While the filesystem lookup will return the same exact file because it's case insensitive, require's cache still treats the two cases as different modules. That's because it has to assume that it runs in a case sensitive environment, so there could actually be two different modules behind that.

That's why it initializes your singleton twice. It actually treats them as two different modules.

You were asking if there's any way to prevent it.
There is a very easy but horrible way to do it. You can patch `global.require` to lowercase your imports:

```
var patchRequire = function () {
    var oldRequire = global.require;
    global.require = function (moduleName) {
        return oldRequire.call(global, moduleName.toLowerCase());
    };
};

patchRequire();
require('Foo-Bar'); // Will require 'foo-bar' instead
```

But please don't do that. Better make sure to keep your imports consistent and use all lower case names separated by dashes.

Comment: thanks, i would only point to that problem because it might be very hard to find this "bug" in a larger environment. And with bug i mean the mispelling of the required module

Comment: Added an example how to make it case insensitive it. Please never use it.

Comment: ja thanks, that is really a brutal way to prevent it :) no i actually thought there is a way to configure node to give a warning or exception or something. i would bet on it - when someone uses nodejs on windows for a greater project they will step into this pitfall. especially when there are more then one developers working on it. thanks again for your help

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme actually I think this whole question is pointless as module identifiers should follow this -> https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md#module-id-format- <- specification. There is explicitly required a camelCase name style and no extension. Module identifiers simply **are not file names**

Comment: Actually the convention in node land seems to be lower case, hyphenated words as seen in http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules That seems to run against the commonjs standard that it actually should follow http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1#Module_Identifiers , but I've only seen hyphenated module names in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

This function check for case sensitivity

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');


const safeRequire = function (requiredPath) {
    const splitted = requiredPath.split('/');
    const upup = splitted.filter((e) => e == '..').join('/');
    let upMost = path.resolve(upup);
    let down = splitted.filter((e) => e !== '..' && e !== '.');
    if (requiredPath.startsWith('./')) {
      upMost = __dirname;
    }
    for (let each of down) {
      const dir = fs.readdirSync(upMost);
      if (!dir.includes(each) && !dir.includes(`${each}.js`)) {
        throw 'Module Not Found (check casing)';
      }
      upMost = path.join(upMost, each);
    }
  return originalRequire.apply(this, [requiredPath]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tim that all paths and file names *should* follow the consistent conventions which ensure the correct case is always used. But sometimes it may be onerous to enforce throughout code, or it may happen that the code with the problem is not under your control. For example, I have encountered this problem where parts of paths to modules may be indirectly supplied as parameters.

So, I have used a work-around which, while a kludge, has the practical advantages of a) avoiding the problem of loading two instances of the same module, b) giving you warning that the situation exists and thereby prompting you to do something about it and c) not modifying the require() function or using your own wrapper for require().

The kludge is to add code into the module itself, so that it will check to see if it has previously been loaded and, if so, issue a warning and return that original instance instead of a new one:

```
"use strict";
if(!global.MYMODULES) global.MYMODULES= {};

// Check if thisModule has already been loaded
if(global.MYMODULES.thisModule){

     // issue a warning and use the original module
    console.log("*****\n*   WARNING: [thisModule.js] is being required from somewhere using module path or module name with the wrong case - INVESTIGATE!!!\n*****");
    module.exports = global.MYMODULES.thisModule;
} else {

// **************************
// The whole code of the thisModule goes here
// **************************

    // Save reference to this original module instance
    global.MYMODULES.thisModule = module.exports;
};
```