# Require is working even with wrong sensitive

Tags: node.js, macos, filesystems

I'm using the `require` function to require a file called Ebooks, and even using the wrong sensitive case, is working:

```
const a = require('./ebooks');
const b = require('./Ebooks');
const c = require('./eBooks');
```

All this examples above are working. I'm using a Mac OSX. Is there any configuration that make this work? Can i disable?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs require - module name case sensitive issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289065/nodejs-require-module-name-case-sensitive-issue)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac your filesystem is case-insensitive by default.  That might be the reason and if that is the case then it is possible you won't be able to change it unless you reformat your partition.  But this is just a guess.